# Как вывести количество фотографий у объявления таким образом?

Tags: php

Xочу вывести количество фотографий в обьявлении по условию, если количество фотографий 0 или 1 то мы скрываем иконку и число, а если количество фотографий больше одного например (2,3,6,9 итд) то мы показываем иконку и число.

```
<div class="catalog-list__img-count">
   <i class="fa fa-camera white"></i> <? echo str_replace("0", '', $v['imgs']); ?>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Покажите пожалуйста как должно быть правильно.

Comment: Что содержится в этой переменной `$v['imgs']`, покажи `print_r($v['imgs'])`, с несколькими `image`

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно просто добавить блок `if` в котором проверить кол-во кратинок исходя из вашей переменной(если в ней действительно только число):

```
<? if ($v['imgs'] > 1):?>
    <div class="catalog-list__img-count">
       <i class="fa fa-camera white"></i> <? echo str_replace("0", '', $v['imgs']); ?>
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```